# SharePoint List Error

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have 2 sharepoint lists on a site.

- They have the same columns (defined from a datatype)
- They contain the same type of data, but for a different product
- They are accessed in the same way (CAML) under the same service account.

thing is today 1 of the lists cannot be queried any more (1pm today), it returns a Soap Exception.

The logs show nothing helpful nor does the eventlog

I have tried to reboot the server but the problem persists.

I have checked

- The columns are still the same
- The user account can still access both lists
- The List ID (GUID) is correct

Example Query

```
<Query xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <Where>
           <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name="Item_x0020_ID" />
                <Value Type="Number">1</Value>
           </Contains>
      </Where>
 </Query>
```

can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the error.

User turned on indexing in the sharepoint list. This alter the way the SQL will be parsed. Causing a SQL error.

turned the index off and it worked!